# Old mobile home wiring, outlets stopped working

Tags: lighting, repair, kitchens

Yesterday 3 of my outlets stopped working.

Earlier this winter 2 got burnt and I haven't replaced them yet, but they're on the other side of the house.

The 3 that stopped working are all around each other.

One showed hot/ground reverse and had nothing plugged into it (near the kitchen).

One showed open neutral but has 1 extension cord and a surge protector to my saltwater tank, but nothing got wet or anything and it didn't do anything open neutral (by the front door).

The other had my computer and printer plugged into it and also showed open neutral (in-between the other two).

Nothing is plugged into them and I know digital plug in meters suck. I'm not sure what do and I'm kind of panicing because I don't have the money to call an electrician.

please help, my mobile home was done in 94 its a double wide.

Comment: Are the other outlets in the home working correctly? Is this isolated to one circuit or are many circuits showing problems?

Comment: When you say "burned" do you mean like arcing from unplugging something or like the outlet actually caught fire behind the cover plate?

Comment: This is a serious safety issue and seems beyond your level of expertise to repair, going by the wording of your issue. As much as this is a DIY site, I'd recommend you get a professional electrician for this. Perhaps you can pay over time or barter for the repair.

Comment: the other outlets are working fine and by burnt I mean the outlet caught on fire behind it bc my family was overusing it.

Comment: I had the same problem. Was also tripping a breaker at times. A friend explained to me that the cause of this is the fact that mobile homes are made cheap. Once you have some run hot while plugged in the plugs will just get worse. Cheap plastic. We replaced every plug in the house with new, better made ,safety UL approved and haven't had a problem since.

Comment: Can you pull one out with the breaker for that circuit turned off and post a photo of how it's hooked up inside the box?

Answer (score 2):

## Hire an electrician.

If your outlets are catching fire, there’s a significant safety problem present since your house clearly isn’t wired to code. Electricity is dangerous in ways that aren’t obvious to a layperson, but a trained professional should be able to safely solve your problem for you.

It’ll cost you some money, but it’ll cost you less money than buying a new house would if your house burns down due to dodgy wiring - especially since it’s possible your insurance might refuse to pay for it due to a pre-existing flaw of the property that you knew of and failed to take steps to correct.